# how to control 12v 600ma motor using raspberry pi

Tags: python, relay

I have a 12v 600ma motor. I want to control it with the raspberry pi gpio pins.

How to draw that much of current from raspberry pi gpio pins to drive that motor.

Please suggest me any cicuit diagram or board.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to draw 600mA at 12V from any pins (especially GPIO) on the Pi.

You could use an external power supply with a relay that is controlled by the Pi'should GPIO pins.

I've needed to draw 6v at 120mA before, and what I did was cut the cable on my power supply and attach a relay to it, with the relay controlled by one of the Pi's pins, from there I wrote a very simple Python program to turn the relay on/off.

Comment: For those like me (software engineer, no electrical engineering background) this is called (roughly) a 12v a high/low trigger relay with isolation. You can get a single channel one for a couple of dollars